# Remove "obsolte" merge commits

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-rebase

This is probably a relatively easy question to answer but I don't seem to be able to come up with the solution myself (or find it on the net). So I'm counting on you!! :)

***Short:***

In a history where I've merged a *feature* branch into *master* several times over the course of time, I'd like to get rid of all those intermediary merge commits.

***Long:***

To illustrate, I have set up a very simple testing repo. Its history looks like this:

```
A---B---D---E-------H  [master]
     \ /           /
      C-------F---G  [feature]
```

D and H are the merge commits where I merged *feature* into *master*. Now I would like to get rid of the first merge commit (D) to arrive at the following history:

```
A---B---E-------H  [master]
     \         /
      C---F---G  [feature]
```

What I tried is this:

- `git checkout master`
- `git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges "A"`
- remove commit "D" from the rebase list

But the history ended up looking like this:

```
A---B---C---E-------H  [master]
         \         /
          ----F---G [feature]
```

The problem here is that C is now part of *master*'s history. This means I can for example no longer easily remove *feature* from *master*'s history.

The point is I want to keep the two branches as much separate as possible, so if, say, I decided to remove *feature* alltogether I could just reset *master* to E and do a `git branch -D feature`.

This is probably very easy to achieve, but somehow I just don't see how.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Tangent: The aim of a feature branch is to perform a single, final, merge.  If you were able to merge half-way through without breaking the mainline, then arguably you had already completed an atomic feature.

Comment: Agree with Oli Charlesworth, also, assuming you've shared master at some point after committing D, you can't do this without altering public history (which is generally a bad idea).

Comment: Thanks @OliCharlesworth and @AngeloGenovese! I never shared the repo. In my case, the branch I called _feature_ here is not really introducing a feature but rather does some cosmetic modifications that I never want to share but, say, use while developing. So I want to be able to completely remove them from the mainline at any time -- hence the need to get rid of all the intermediary merge commits.

Answer (score 0):

You need not only to remove commit "D", but also commit "C" when rebasing (with, as you correctly statet, with `--preserve-merges`). This way you make sure your "master" will contain only "A", "B", "E" and "H". You should also rebase on "B" (not on "A") to make sure "C" is referencing the parent same commit as "E" does after the rebase.

When you are doing this, you will probably get conflicts, because "E" was previously built on the now gone "D". You need to resolve them probably manually and continue the rebasing with `git rebase --continue`.